# Implications of weakly consistent ConcurrentSkipListSet

Tags: java, concurrency, iterator

Using a [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) I have observed some wired behaviour, that I suspect is caused by the weakly consistency of the concurrent set.

The JavaDoc has this to say on that topic:

> Most concurrent Collection implementations (including most Queues)
>   also differ from the usual java.util conventions in that their
>   Iterators and Spliterators provide weakly consistent rather than
>   fast-fail traversal:
>
> - they may proceed concurrently with other operations
> - they will never throw ConcurrentModificationException
> - they are guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and may (but are not guaranteed to) reflect
>     any modifications subsequent to construction.

This is the code that I use:

```
private final ConcurrentSkipListSet<TimedTask> sortedEvents;

public TimedUpdatableTaskList(){
    Comparator<TimedTask> comparator = 
        (task1, task2) -> task1.getExecutionTime().compareTo(task2.getExecutionTime());
    sortedEvents = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(comparator);
}

public void add(TimedTask task) {
    log.trace("Add task {}", task);
    sortedEvents.add(task);
}

public void handleClockTick(ClockTick event) {
    LocalDateTime now = date.getCurrentDate();
    logContent("Task list BEFORE daily processing ("+now+")");
    for (Iterator<TimedTask> iterator = sortedEvents.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        TimedTask task = iterator.next();
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(task.getExecutionTime(),
                "The exectution time of the task may not be null");
        if (task.getExecutionTime().isBefore(now)) {
            log.trace("BEFORE: Execute task {} scheduled for {} on {}",
                    task, task.getExecutionTime(), now);
            try {
                task.run();
                iterator.remove();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Failed to execute timed task", e);
            }
            log.trace("AFTER: Execute task {} scheduled for {} on {}",
                    task, task.getExecutionTime(), now);
        }
        if (task.getExecutionTime().isAfter(now)) {
            break; // List is sorted
        }
    }
    logContent("Task list AFTER daily processing");
}

private void logContent(String prefix) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sortedEvents.stream().forEach(task ->sb.append(task).append(" "));
    log.trace(prefix + ": "+sb.toString());
}
```

At occasion I can see log output like this:

```
2018-05-19 13:46:00,453 [pool-3-thread-1] TRACE ... - Add task AIRefitTask{ship=Mercurius, scheduled for: 1350-07-16T08:45}
2018-05-19 13:46:00,505 [pool-3-thread-5] TRACE ... - Task list BEFORE daily processing (1350-07-16T09:45): AIRefitTask{ship=Tidewalker, scheduled for: 1350-07-16T08:45} AIRepairTask{ship=Hackepeter, scheduled for: 1350-07-16T13:45} ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.engine.event.task.WeaponConstructionTask@680da167 ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.engine.player.DailyPlayerUpdater@6e22f1ba AIRepairTask{ship=St. Bonivatius, scheduled for: 1350-07-17T03:45} AIRepairTask{ship=Hackepeter, scheduled for: 1350-07-17T05:45} ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.engine.event.task.WeeklyLoanerCheckTask@47571ace
```

These are two almost consecutive log lines. Please note that they are executed on different threads. The `TimedTask` entry that is added is not listed in the second log line.

Am I correct in my assumption that this is due to the weakly consistency? If so, would this also imply that the `iterator.next()` retrieves a different entry than `iterator.remove()` deletes?

What I am observing, is that this added entry is never processed and does not show up in the concurrent set at any time.

What would be a good solution to avoid this? What comes to my mind, is create a copy of the set and iterate over that one, as it is acceptable, that entries can be processed in a future iteration, as long as they are processed. Looking at [Weakly consistent iterator by ConcurrentHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079344/weakly-consistent-iterator-by-concurrenthashmap) suggests the iteration already happens on a copy of the set, so this might not change anything.

*EDIT* Sample implementation of a `TimedTask`:

```
class AIRefitTask extends TimedTask {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(AIRefitTask.class);

    private AsyncEventBus clientServerEventBus;

    private ShipWeaponsLocationFactory shipWeaponLocationFactory;

    private ShipService shipService;

    private final IShip ship;
    private final EShipUpgrade level;
    private final IShipyard shipyard;

    public AIRefitTask(LocalDateTime executionTime, IShip ship, EShipUpgrade upgrade, IShipyard shipyard) {
        super();
        setExecutionTime(executionTime);
        LOGGER.debug("Add AIRefitTask for {} to be done at {}", ship.getName(), executionTime);
        this.ship = ship;
        this.level = upgrade;
        this.shipyard = shipyard;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        EShipUpgrade currentLevel = ship.getShipUpgradeLevel();
        while (currentLevel != level) {
            ship.upgrade();
            List<IWeaponSlot> oldWeaponSlots = ship.getWeaponSlots();
            List<IWeaponSlot> newWeaponSlots = shipWeaponLocationFactory.getShipWeaponsLocation(ship.getShipType(), level);
            ship.setWeaponSlots(newWeaponSlots);
            for (IWeaponSlot slot : oldWeaponSlots) {
                if (slot.getWeapon().isPresent()) {
                    EWeapon weapon = (EWeapon) slot.getWeapon().get();
                    if (slot instanceof SecondaryLargeWeaponSlot) {
                        if (!shipService.isLargeWeapon(weapon)) { // ignore large weapons in secondary slots
                            shipService.placeWeapon(weapon, ship);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Not secondary slot
                        shipService.placeWeapon(weapon, ship);
                    }
                }
            }
            currentLevel = ship.getShipUpgradeLevel();
        }
        ship.setAvailable(true);
        shipyard.removeCompletedUpgrade(ship);
        LOGGER.debug("Refited ship {}", ship.getName());
        clientServerEventBus.post(new RefitFinishedEvent(ship));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AIRefitTask{ship="+ship.getUuid()+", scheduled for: "+getExecutionTime()+"}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's that log come from?

Comment: First line is from the `add` method and the second the first log in the for loop within `handleClockTick`.

Comment: What if the execution time for `task1` == `task2`? Won't that drop duplicates?

Comment: I don't think so, as the equality of objects is not only based on the execution time, but some other parameters as well. However the `TimedTask` does not implement `hashCode` or `equals`, so the implementations would be the ones from `Object`.

Comment: @hotzst please read the contract of `Comparator`, as your set is not using `equals` / `hashCode`. Take a simple example of comparing strings by their length only. "a" comp "b" is 0, causing the set to drop "b" when both are added.

Comment: @BenManes: the missing `hashCode` and `equals` may have contributed to the problem, but adding them did not solve it. What is more, when adding a call to `logContent` after the adding of an item the item is not contained in the list, which is an issue with the iteration and not the containment.

Comment: Please again look at your comparator and construction of the SortedSet. I have not been asking about equals and hashCode, but that your set is configured to drop entries based on the comparator. You are misunderstanding how a sorted set works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BenManes pointed out in his comment, the issue is with the Comparator used. When the result of the Comparator is 0, even through the two tasks are not equal, entries will be overridden. In effect, the Comparator should consider the same fields as `hashCode` and `equals`.
Use a `Comparator` implementation like this:

```
public int compare(TimedTask task1, TimedTask task2) {
    int executionTimeBasedComparisonResult = task1.getExecutionTime().compareTo(task2.getExecutionTime());
    if (executionTimeBasedComparisonResult == 0) { // two execution times are equal
        return task1.getUuid().compareTo(task2.getUuid());
    }
    return executionTimeBasedComparisonResult;
}
```

With an implementation like this the comparison is based on the execution time and when both of them are the same (comparison is 0) ensure they are ordered based on their UUID.

For the use case the order of tasks with the same execution time is not relevant.